# How to fix the error 'API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Encountered " "FROM" "from "" at .... Was expecting: ")"'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

I am trying to run a bigquery api call using the query string(attached in the code) from appscript; The query runs perfectly fine in bigquery UI

I have tried the following with no success:
1. include parentheses in orders.creation_date in the query string
2. replace orders with the actual table table i.e [my-project:theservices.theservice_order_item]

```
/**
 * Runs a BigQuery query and logs the results in a spreadsheet.
 */
function runQuery() {

  var projectId = 'my-project';

  var request = {
    query:  
    "SELECT  extract(date from orders.creation_date) as the_date \n FROM [my-project:theservices.theservice_order_item] AS orders LIMIT 10;"   
  }; 

};
```

Following is the error I get:
API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Encountered " "FROM" "from "" at line 1, column 22. Was expecting: ")" ... (line 23, file "Code")

Comment: what happens if you remove \n?

Comment: Still getting the following error: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Encountered " "FROM" "from "" at line 1, column 22. Was expecting: ")" ...

Comment: Ok. This query doesn't run in the UI. It has a mix of #standardSQL and #legacySQL. "The query runs perfectly fine in bigquery UI" - nah.

Comment: yeap on web ui, I use the following code which works fine:SELECT EXTRACT(date FROM orders.creation_date)
FROM ``data-analytics-related.theservices.theservice_order_item`` AS orders

Comment: I have used sting literals on this data-analytics-related.theservices.theservice_order_item

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [App Script BigQuery Standard SQL insert or update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091333/app-script-bigquery-standard-sql-insert-or-update-statement):

> You need to set the useLegacySql flag/parameter to false, to indicate that you want to use standard SQL, like so:

```
var job = {
configuration: {
  query: {
    query: 'SELECT ....',
    useLegacySql: false
    }
```

Additionally, when a table looks like this - that's #legacySQL:

```
FROM [my-project:theservices.theservice_order_item]
```

In #standardSQL the table should be enclosed in tilde '`' and has a '.' between the project and dataset name:

```
FROM `my-project.theservices.theservice_order_item`
```

Comment: inserting the useLegacySql: false worked.... Thanks a lot for the help!